# Config Server details from application.yml not fetched

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, java-17

I am migrating Spring Batch using Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3 (with Spring Batch 5) which uses config server to fetch environment specific properties. My properties is like this.

```
logging.logstash= abc1.uk.dev.net:5001
spring.application.name= myservice-backend
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding= true

#--- dev profile
spring.config.activate.on-profile= dev
logging.logstash= abc1.uk.dev.net:5001
spring.application.name= myservice-backend
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding= true
spring.config.import= configserver:http://localhost:8088
spring.cloud.config.label= release(_)V5.1

#--- sit profile
spring.config.activate.on-profile= sit
logging.logstash= abc1.uk.dev.net:5001
spring.application.name= myservice-backend
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding= true
spring.config.import= configserver:http://localhost:8088
spring.cloud.config.label= release(_)V5.1
```

It looks like it doesnt seem to pick up the correct environment and fails to load anything. Any idea what could be wrong. If I just put one environment in the application.properties file then it seems to load everything

```
logging.logstash= abc1.uk.dev.net:5001
spring.application.name= myservice-backend
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding= true
spring.config.activate.on-profile= dev
logging.logstash= abc1.uk.dev.net:5001
spring.config.import= configserver:http://localhost:8088
spring.cloud.config.label= release(_)V5.1
```

This is my pom.xml.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>2.0</snakeyaml.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- config server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Also in spring-batch service I cant seem to load test properties from src/test/resources/application-test.yml, it works only with src/test/resources/application-test.properties

Any idea what could be missing here or how could I achieve what I am trying to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bootstrap dependency was included which screwed things up. Everything works like charm after removing it.

Answer (score 0):

This format of writing is used in .properties file. For yaml files you need to change your format like this

```
logging:
  logstash: abc1.uk.dev.net:5001
    
spring:
  application:
    name: myservice-backend
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```